# How to call php function with passing parameter and when user click on some test the function has to call?

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner in php.I want to call a give click  action to the text when user click on text it has to call the php function and I am passing parameter to that function.

the code is like this

this is in php;

```
for($v=0;$v<10;$v++){

echo '.$version[$v].';

}
```

I want to call method graph($v) with passing parameter when user click on  '.$version[$v].' this text.

Comment: Php is client side and what you are asking is server side. You can pass data but you can not control the DOM with php.

Comment: @pr1nc3 There are a couple of ways (ajax or a form), but OP is _unclear_  and didn't do any research efford.

Comment: Yes this is for passing data but to control the dom like "on click" you cant do it with solid php.

Comment: @pr1nc3 You can. Just as long as it's done before output.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use JavaScript for check where the user clicks and use Ajax to communicate with the server

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: He doesn't have the nessesary reputation to comment yet. That being said: Please don't use answers for comments. Go answer questions that you can actually _answer_. Once you've gained 50 reputation, you'll be able to comment. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment?rq=1

Comment: I don't now to do this using ajax. But how to call PHP function in javascript?

Comment: that's exactly what we said, it's impossible. PHP is server side and JavaScript is client side.
There is no PHP on the client side
you need to use Ajax.

Comment: I don't know Ajax.Can u share some examples or link to do this?